# col-sm-4 not fitting three columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, col

When I use col-sm-4, only two columns fit. This happens even when I view the webpage at the most zoomed out. There are two columns showing instead of three. I tried to edit the margins, but that didn't help. [Here is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYqiR.png) This seems very amateur, but I am in fact an amateur. Thanks.

HTML

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="eventDisplay">
    <h2>Available Events</h2>
    <div class="eventDisplay row">

      <div class="eventDisplay col-sm-4">
        <div class="thumb">
          <span>Event Name</span>
        </div>

        <h2 style="font-weight: bold;">September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm <br/><br/> @Rouge Valley Park</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dignissim nisi mauris, quis semper ex vehicula ut. Etiam cursus convallis ullamcorper. Donec a sagittis ipsum. Sed ut arcu non augue aliquam finibus nec quis massa.
        </p>

        <div class="centerButton">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="mailto:tempEmail?Subject=Event Title &body=Name:">get planting</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      (this time 3)

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.eventdisplay.row {
  margin: 30px;
}

.eventDisplay.col-sm-4 {
  margin: 50px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #B8B8B8;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.thumb {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url("img/trees.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Bootstrap4 so why not start by using the [Card Component](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/)?

Comment: Thank you so much. I just wish someone had told me about the Card Component before I spent all that time trying to figure it out. Anyhow, is there a reason why it's displaying in two columns instead of three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I look at least: you're nesting this class, `.eventDisplay` 3 levels deep for some reason and trying to use it in conjunction with either a `.row` or a `.col-*-*` which is upsetting the properties of those classes and causing the grid to break. As a very general rule, place your content inside the grid

```
.container
  .row
    .col-*-*
      .content
```

Here are two examples: one that cleans up your current code and one using a modified [Card Component](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/).

**Example 1: Sort of what you have.**

```css
.eventDisplay {
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #B8B8B8;
}
.thumb {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4">

      <div class="eventDisplay">
        <div class="thumb">
          <span>Event Name</span>
        </div>
        <h2>Available Events</h2>
        <h2>September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm <br/><br/> @Rouge Valley Park</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dignissim nisi mauris, quis semper ex vehicula ut. Etiam cursus convallis ullamcorper. Donec a sagittis ipsum. Sed ut arcu non augue aliquam finibus nec quis massa.</p>
        <div class="centerButton">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="mailto:tempEmail?Subject=Event Title &body=Name:">get planting</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">

      <div class="eventDisplay">
        <div class="thumb">
          <span>Event Name</span>
        </div>
        <h2>Available Events</h2>
        <h2>September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm <br/><br/> @Rouge Valley Park</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dignissim nisi mauris, quis semper ex vehicula ut. Etiam cursus convallis ullamcorper. Donec a sagittis ipsum. Sed ut arcu non augue aliquam finibus nec quis massa.</p>
        <div class="centerButton">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="mailto:tempEmail?Subject=Event Title &body=Name:">get planting</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">

      <div class="eventDisplay">
        <div class="thumb">
          <span>Event Name</span>
        </div>
        <h2>Available Events</h2>
        <h2>September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm <br/><br/> @Rouge Valley Park</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dignissim nisi mauris, quis semper ex vehicula ut. Etiam cursus convallis ullamcorper. Donec a sagittis ipsum. Sed ut arcu non augue aliquam finibus nec quis massa.</p>
        <div class="centerButton">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="mailto:tempEmail?Subject=Event Title &body=Name:">get planting</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

**Example 2: Using Bootstrap v4 Cards.**

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.card.eventDisplay {
  box-shadow: .25rem .25rem 1.75rem #B8B8B8;
  border: none;
}
.btn.btn-black {
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
}
.card-img.card-img-bottom {
  border-radius: .25rem .25rem 0 0;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) and (max-width: 61em) {
  .event:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .event:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 event">

      <div class="card eventDisplay">
        <img class="card-img card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt="alt">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h4 class="card-title">Event 1</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">@Rouge Valley Park</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-black">Get Planning</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 event">

      <div class="card eventDisplay">
        <img class="card-img card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt="alt">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h4 class="card-title">Event 2</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">@Rouge Valley Park</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-black">Get Planning</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 event">

      <div class="card eventDisplay">
        <img class="card-img card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt="alt">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h4 class="card-title">Event 3</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">@Rouge Valley Park</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title
            and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-black">Get Planning</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 event">

      <div class="card eventDisplay">
        <img class="card-img card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt="alt">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h4 class="card-title">Event 4</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">@Rouge Valley Park</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-black">Get Planning</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 event">

      <div class="card eventDisplay">
        <img class="card-img card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt="alt">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h4 class="card-title">Event 5</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">@Rouge Valley Park</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title
            and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-black">Get Planning</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 event">

      <div class="card eventDisplay">
        <img class="card-img card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt="alt">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h4 class="card-title">Event 6</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">@Rouge Valley Park</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-black">Get Planning</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 event">

      <div class="card eventDisplay">
        <img class="card-img card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt="alt">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h4 class="card-title">Event 7</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">@Rouge Valley Park</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-black">Get Planning</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 event">

      <div class="card eventDisplay">
        <img class="card-img card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt="alt">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h4 class="card-title">Event 8</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">@Rouge Valley Park</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title
            and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-black">Get Planning</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 event">

      <div class="card eventDisplay">
        <img class="card-img card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt="alt">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h4 class="card-title">Event 9</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">@Rouge Valley Park</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-black">Get Planning</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 event">

      <div class="card eventDisplay">
        <img class="card-img card-img-bottom img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt="alt">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h4 class="card-title">Event 10</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">September 20 | 9:00am - 4:00pm</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">@Rouge Valley Park</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title
            and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-black">Get Planning</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer!

Comment: I spend nine hours on this today and I just want to say I am so incredibly grateful for your help. I can go to sleep in peace now. I wish I had known about Bootstrap cards before I pursued this, but once again, thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome, and always keep the documentation in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

1. remove any margin
2. before any row add a div with class `row` in your case put three `col-sm-4` in a `div` with class `row`
3. add this to all element `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: I tried removing all the margins, and all three fit, but they were touching. Even if I add a 1px margin, the three no longer fit on one row. I don't want them to touch, I want space between each column.